# C# display specific item in listview

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

I'm doing an assignment involve searching in a listview. I have a textbox and a listview that bind to a list<>. And I want to display the item in the listview which is similar to what I type in the textbox, or at least scroll to it. Here is my code:
XAML code:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MathDictionary"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:MathDictionary.ViewModel"
x:Class="MathDictionary.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="SearchT" TextChanged="SearchT_TextChanged_1"></TextBox>
            <ListView x:Name="ListWord" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Words}" SelectionChanged="ListWord_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>                              
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding words}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>                
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="40,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="KeyT" FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ValueT" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>            
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

And the code I want to call when typing:

```
private void SearchT_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchT.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = ListWord.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var item = ListWord.Items[i];
                if (item.ToString().Contains(SearchT.Text.ToString()))
                {

                    //Display the item or scroll to it

                }
                else
                {
                    //Do something here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
private void SearchT_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchT.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = ListWord.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var item = ListWord.Items[i];
                if (item.ToString().Contains(SearchT.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    ListWord.ScrollIntoView(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well it did work but the item is only scroll to not hightlight or selected, is there a way to hightlight it?

Comment: I think you can add
ListWord.Items[i].Selected = true;
ListWord.Select();

Comment: ListWord.Items[i] does not have .Selected just Equals, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString

Comment: How about ListWord.SelectedItem = item; ?